# Запретить зацикливание функции

Tags: javascript

Функция onSuccess выполняется бесконечное число раз, так как постоянно запрашивает координаты с GPS приемника. 
В ней находится функция createMap, которую необходимо выполнить только один раз. 
Как этого добиться? Вынести функцию за пределы данной функции тоже не могу, т.к. в нее в качестве параметров передается значение значение переменных из данной функции.

```
  watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function(position) {onSuccess(position, arrMyLatLng);}, onError, options);  
  function onSuccess(position, arrMyLatLng) 
  {

  var latitude , longitude ;     
  latitude = position.coords.latitude ;
  longitude = position.coords.longitude;
  var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);

  createMap(myLatLng, arrMyLatLng);// данная функция будет выполняться бесконечное число раз. Необходимо только один раз
  map.panTo(myLatLng) ;
```

}

Comment: зачем вам каждый раз новая карта?

Comment: Мне нужна каждый раз новая карта. Для этого я и спрашиваю, как избавиться от цикличности.

Comment: вы на каждый маркер создаете новую карту. Это вам и в самом деле надо?

Answer (score 5):

Самый простой вариант:

```
var mapCreated = 0;
function onSuccess(position, arrMyLatLng) 
{
  if( !mapCreated )
  {
    createMap(myLatLng, arrMyLatLng); mapCreated++;
  }  
}
```

Comment: этот способ не подходит. Так как ф-я onSuccess вложена в другую функцию.

Comment: А вынести флаг ещё выше что-то мешает?

Comment: Пробовал. Но это не помогает. функция не видит эту переменную, даже если она глобальная.

Comment: Хм, как это "не видит"? До этого момента я думал, что такого не может быть. Сможете сделать пример, воспроизводящий это, на jsfiddle?

Comment: createMap ваша же функция ? в ней флаг и проверяйте 
типа
http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/Mcur3/ (там jquery, но это не обязательно) ну и [так тоже работает](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/Mcur3/3/)

Answer (score 1):

В jQuery, например, есть такая штука как .one() (http://api.jquery.com/one/)

Comment: не при делах one здесь, one это повесить обработчик события и снять его после выполнения, вы предлагаете кастомные события вешать на какой-то элемент, а потом вызывать trigger ?

Comment: Если человеку изначально что-то мешает поставить простейшую проверку вида if (!$boolean) { ... $boolean = !$boolean; } то почему бы и не предложить извращенный вариант с внешним обработчиком?

Answer (score 0):

```
onSuccess = (function() {
var created = false;
return function (position, arrMyLatLng) {
    var latitude , longitude ;     
    latitude = position.coords.latitude ;
    longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    if (!created) {
        createMap(myLatLng, arrMyLatLng);
        created = true;
    }
    map.panTo(myLatLng) ;
};
}());
```

Comment: могли бы поблагодарить людей, которые вам помогли.

Comment: то есть один раз построили карту и забыли. Тогда как у вас будет происходить "Мне нужна каждый раз новая карта."? Какой каждый раз, каждый раз чего?  
Правильно сравнивать время полученных координат с временем полученных координат до него, а также точность полученных координат

    position.timestamp < freshness_threshold && 
      position.coords.accuracy < accuracy_threshold

Смотрите примеры тут: [W3C Geolocation API Specification](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html)

Comment: опечатка была. исправил.